# Close a MS Access form without any dirty data saving

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

New user to MS Access here. I'm creating a form for insertion into my database (simple user info database : address name phone etc). However I've realized that anytime a user writes ANYTHING on the form, access saves it, even if it's a single letter. I have a save button on my form and I was wondering is there a way to have the form only save when the user clicks save? I'm completely new to access so any specific examples / explanations would be greatly appreciated(ex if I would have to put in vba lines how would I go about that).

Answer (score 1):

That's the default behaviour of an Access form.

If you don't want that, set `Cancel = True` in the *BeforeUpdate* event of the form.